# Where to find free or paid database of European postal addresses?

Tags: database, geolocation, gis, postal-code

I'm searching for database for delivery service. Delivery rate calculates based on ZIP code. The only good product I found is geopostcodes.com, is there any more? E.g. geonames.org is good but contains not enough data.

Comment: This is not a good question for the StackOverflow site. Do you have a question about some code that you have written? http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 3):

How about this free solution http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/.

Comment: As I said Geonames is not enough, mainly because of postal codes

Comment: Uups, sorry I was to fast. Should it free solution?